# Nesting a case statement within a for loop

Tags: bash

I'm trying to follow the instructions below in order to create one directory containing four subdirectories inside, each of these latter with five new empty files:

> 1. Create a directory with the name of the first positional parameter (choose whatever name you want).
> 2. Use a for loop to do the following:
>
>    2.1. Within the directory, create four subdirectories with these names: rent, utilities, groceries, other.
>
>    2.2. Within the for loop, use case statements to determine which subdirectory is currently being handled in the loop. You will need 4
>      cases.
>
>    2.3. Within each case, use a for loop to create 5 empty files with the touch command. Each subdirectory must have its 5 files inside.

So far, I have created a directory and several subdirectories at once, each of them with a specific name, as you can see in my code:

```
mkdir $1
for folder in $1; do 
mkdir -p $1/{Rent,Utilities,Groceries,Other}
done
```

However, I'm stuck in the following step (2.2.), and I don't know how to continue from here.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't use `folder` anywhere. Also, the loop runs just once, with `foled=$1`.

Comment: Also, doublequote the variables, otherwise your script can't handle arguments like `Program Files`.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to use case statements for each of the subdirectories instead of a single line of code which would create all of them at once, @choroba. Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: `man bash` documents the `case`  construct. See for example [Bash Beginners Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html) for some examples. It's not clear what you should do in each case, though.

Comment: As I understand it, each case statement would just contain a new for loop in order to create the files

Comment: But how will be the new for loops different to each other?

Comment: @choroba Each of them would create the files in a different subdirectory (rent, utilities, groceries or other). I guess that should be specified somehow either in the loop or in the case statement and so that would make them different from each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I read it, this is what 2.1 and 2.2 are asking for:

```
for folder in rent utilities groceries other; do 
    mkdir "$1/$folder"

    case $folder in
        rent)
            ...
            ;;
        utilities)
            ...
            ;;
        groceries)
            ...
            ;;
        other)
            ...
            ;;
    esac
done
```

I've left the cases blank for you to fill out.

For what it's worth, I would never code a script this way. Having a `case` statement inside a `for` loop is an anti-pattern. The loop really adds no value. If this weren't an assignment I would code it differently:

```
mkdir "$1"

# Populate rent/ directory.
mkdir "$1"/rent
touch "$1"/rent/...

# Populate utilities/ directory.
mkdir "$1"/utilities
touch "$1"/utilities/...

# Populate groceries/ directory.
mkdir "$1"/groceries
touch "$1"/groceries/...

# Populate other/ directory.
mkdir "$1"/other
touch "$1"/other/...
```